# Converting minutes to days, hours, and remaining minutes

Tags: javascript

Trying to convert minutes per total number of episodes into days, hours, and minutes but I can't figure out the proper formula for hours.

```js
function minToDays(min, ep) {
  let days = parseInt((min * ep) / 1440);
  let hours = parseInt(((min * ep) % 60));
  let remainingMin = hours % 60;
  return `${days} day(s) and ${hours} hour(s) and ${remainingMin} minutes(s).`;
}
console.log(minToDays(20, 800)); //11 days, 2 hours, 40 minutes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit clunky, but here's a quick way to see the logic - each time you need to see what minutes remain.  I'm sure someone with more time will give you a more elegnat answer:

```js
function minToDays(min, ep) {
  let days = Math.floor((min * ep) / 1440);
  let remainingTime = parseInt((min*ep) - Math.floor((days *1440)));
  let hours = Math.floor((remainingTime / 60));
  let remainingMin = Math.floor(remainingTime - (hours*60));
  return `${days} day(s) and ${hours} hour(s) and ${remainingMin} minutes(s).`;
}
console.log(minToDays(20, 800)); //11 days, 2 hours, 40 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is textbook problem. The operator is called **[Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)**

What is Remainder: This originated from Math, or I think this is plain Math operator, used in Programming and in College Math.

**How Remainder Operator is used/defined**

Remainder operator (I know this operator as Modulo operator from Mathematics) just calculates the Remainder.

`101%10`-> 1

`81%7` ->4

`81/7` -> 11.57

So, Remainder Operator only calculates the remaining after division.

Answer (score 0):

this should do.

```js
function minutesToDays(min,ep ) {
         let totalMinutes = min * ep,
            cd = 24 * 60 ,
            ch = 60 ,
            day = Math.floor(totalMinutes / cd),
            hour = Math.floor((totalMinutes - day * cd) / ch),
            minute = Math.round(totalMinutes - day * cd - hour * ch),
            pad = n => { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; };
        if (minute === 60) {
            hour++;
            minute = 0;
        }
        if (hour === 24) {
            day++;
            hour = 0;
        }
        return [(day > 0 ? `${day} days` : ""), (hour > 0 ? `${pad(hour)} hours ` : ''), `${pad(minute)} minutes`].join(" ");
    }
    console.log(minutesToDays(20, 800))
```